# tsc tries to compile everything in my monorepo rather than just one package

Tags: typescript, monorepo, tsc, pnpm, turborepo

I am at my wits end with what I imagine is a trivial problem, but multiple devs at my company have been flummoxed by this for some time.

We are mid-migration to a monorepo which will include our legacy codebase, largely so that we can pull in the types from our old API. We are using Turborepo and pnpm.

The relevant part of the file structure is as follows

```
├── services
│   ├── backend
│   │   ├── $some_files
│   ├── nest-api
│       ├── $some_files
```

Some code in the `backend` package includes an `import type { Baz } from "@acme/nest-api/src/modules/foo/bar/baz"` statement which pulls in a type from the `nest-api` package. When tsc is run on the `backend` package, tsc attempts to build the entire `nest-api` package using the config from the `tsconfig` file in the `backend` package, which fails, because the `nest-api` package requires a more permissive config.

In the tsc logs, it refers to the files like `../nest-api/src/modules/foo/bar/baz.ts:15` - I am very confused as to how tsc is escaping its scope of all the files in `backend/src` and getting to this directory. Is there a simple tsconfig setting we have missed or is something else afoot?

I appreciate that this is a vague question but I really hope someone can help - I can provide more details if needed but in all honesty I'm not sure exactly what to provide!

Running `turbo run build --filter nextjs` should cause the repo to build successfully. Instead it fails.